# redirect 403 using .htaccess creates ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: php, .htaccess

On my .htaccess i want to redirect all the 403 generated by deny from, to a custom php page
My custom file is called 403page.php

The code below just brings the classic 403 Forbidden white page and my custom page

`deny from xx.xx.xx.xx`

```
ErrorDocument 403 /403page.php
```

Now if I have

```
ErrorDocument 403 http://mywebsite.com/403page.php
```

this will create a page "This page isn't working - redirected too many times."

Any ideas?

Comment: "the classic 403 Forbidden white page and my custom page" - do you mean "and **not** my custom page"?

Comment: The documentation already explains, why _redirecting_ to an error page is generally the wrong thing to do. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#errordocument: _"Note that when you specify an ErrorDocument that points to a remote URL (ie. anything with a method such as http in front of it), Apache HTTP Server will send a redirect to the client to tell it where to find the document, even if the document ends up being on the same server. [...]"_

Comment: _"[...] This has several implications, the most important being that the client will not receive the original error status code, but instead will receive a redirect status code. This in turn can confuse web robots and other clients which try to determine if a URL is valid using the status code."_